# how to made $price equal to input value

Tags: php, variables

i am new to php, may someone have any solution below?

i wan to set this input value to $price

```
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="20">
```

this is the code the variable get the input value

```
$get = $_GET['subject'];
$p_price =  echo $get ;
```

but the result is

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in ...\classes\class.wci-shortcode.php on line 732

Comment: remove echo... just: ` $p_price = $get; `

Comment: you want to remove the `echo $get;` and replace with `$p_price = $get`; You could also do `$p_price = $_GET['subject'];`

Comment: @JohnConde You are on a mission today

Answer (score 2):

Code like this

```
$get = $_GET['subject'];
echo $get ;
```

You cant store echo statement in a variable. if you want to store value of `$get` variable in another variable do it this way:

```
$p_price = $get;
```